# C# : Creating a Single Bot Service to Support Multiple Bot Applications

Tags: c#, node.js, botframework

This code was on this website https://www.microsoft.com/reallifecode/2017/01/10/creating-a-single-bot-service-to-support-multiple-bot-applications/#comment-148
I am new to bot framework and have written a bot in C# and want to deploy the same bot for n number of users as shown on the webpage. But the given code is in `Node.js`. Is there any way to write the same code in C# asp.net

```
var express = require('express');            
var builder = require('botbuilder');          
var port = process.env.PORT || 3978;         
var app = express();

// a list of client ids, with their corresponding  
// appids and passwords from the bot developer portal.    
// get this from the configuration, a remote API, etc.   
var customersBots = [   
    { cid: 'cid1', appid: '', passwd: '' },  
    { cid: 'cid2', appid: '', passwd: '' },    
    { cid: 'cid3', appid: '', passwd: '' },    
];

// expose a designated Messaging Endpoint for each of the customers 

customersBots.forEach(cust => {

    // create a connector and bot instances for    
    // this customer using its appId and password   
    var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({   
        appId: cust.appid,   
        appPassword: cust.passwd   
     });   
     var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);

     // bing bot dialogs for each customer bot instance   
     bindDialogsToBot(bot, cust.cid);

     // bind connector for each customer on it's dedicated Messaging Endpoint.   
     // bot framework entry should use the customer id as part of the    
     // endpoint url to map to the right bot instance   
     app.post(`/api/${cust.cid}/messages`, connector.listen());     
 });

 // this is where you implement all of your dialogs    
 // and add them on the bot instance   
 function bindDialogsToBot (bot, cid) {    
     bot.dialog('/', [    
         session => {     
           session.send(`Hello... I'm a bot for customer id: '${cid}'`);    
         }    
 ]);    
}    
// start listening for incoming requests    
app.listen(port, () => {    
    console.log(`listening on port ${port}`);    
});
```

Comment: What happened ? Does my answer helped you ?

Comment: @BobSwager Yes it does! thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Resume:

- Create a class and inherit from ICredentialProvider class.
- Then, add your Microsoft appId and password into a Dictionary.
- Add your method to check if it is a valid app; also get password for
  your application.
- Add custom authentication to your `api/messages` controller.

---

First change your `WebApiConfig` :

Should be :

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { action = RouteParameter.Optional, id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Then, your custom authentication class, starting from YourNameSpace:

```
namespace YourNameSpace {
    public class MultiCredentialProvider : ICredentialProvider
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string> Credentials = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { MicrosoftAppID1, MicrosoftAppPassword1},
            { MicrosoftAppID2, MicrosoftAppPassword2}
        };

        public Task<bool> IsValidAppIdAsync(string appId)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(this.Credentials.ContainsKey(appId));
        }

        public Task<string> GetAppPasswordAsync(string appId)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(this.Credentials.ContainsKey(appId) ? this.Credentials[appId] : null);
        }

        public Task<bool> IsAuthenticationDisabledAsync()
        {
            return Task.FromResult(!this.Credentials.Any());
        }
    }
```

After that, add your controller (api/messages) with your custom `BotAuthentication`, plus your static constructor to update the container to use the right `MicorosftAppCredentials` based on identity set by BotAuthentication:

```
[BotAuthentication(CredentialProviderType = typeof(MultiCredentialProvider))]
public class MessagesController : ApiController
{
    static MessagesController()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.Register(c => ((ClaimsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity).GetCredentialsFromClaims())
            .AsSelf()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        builder.Update(Conversation.Container);
    }
```

You can handle now messages by :

```
[BotAuthentication(CredentialProviderType = typeof(MultiCredentialProvider))]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
{
    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    { 
        ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
        Activity reply = activity.CreateReply("it Works!");                       
        await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
    }
}
```

This code is tested and working for my bots.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: I'm using the same code as yours, but my `MultiCredentialProvider` breakpoints were never get hit and I always got the error `Error: The bot's MSA appId or password is incorrect.`

Comment: I'm using 3.8.5 version

Comment: Check your error. You have provided an invalid appId and password. :)