# multicredentials bot in azure functions

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-functions

I want to deploy a Azure Functions Bot that supports multiple Appid. Is there any way to replicate this code for Functions?

[C# : Creating a Single Bot Service to Support Multiple Bot Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44559700/c-sharp-creating-a-single-bot-service-to-support-multiple-bot-applications)

What i need is to use a single function to support several bot channel registration as a message endpoint.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want your function app to serve multiple Bot services as message endpoint, or single function bot serve multiple bot applications?

Comment: "I want to deploy a Azure Functions Bot that supports multiple users"  all bots do this by default, you do not need to make a multi-credential bot for this.  What are the issues you are having?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments. What I need is to configure the function bot to support multiple bot channels registration as the message endpoint. I mean, recognize and validate several appid. Just like in the link. ty

Comment: @JasonSowers You are right, i wrote the post incorrectly. I´ll edit it. thank you.