# Multi-tenant bot data store

Tags: c#, botframework, multi-tenant, azure-table-storage

I've been implementing the following for a multi-tenant azure bot in C# and this works great for authenticating the app credentials.

[C# : Creating a Single Bot Service to Support Multiple Bot Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44559700/c-sharp-creating-a-single-bot-service-to-support-multiple-bot-applications)

https://www.microsoft.com/developerblog/2017/01/10/creating-a-single-bot-service-to-support-multiple-bot-applications/

However, I am wondering if the same is possible for the bot data store as well?
I currently have the standard Azure Table storage bot data store implemented like so which uses a single connection string defined in the web.config:

```
Conversation.UpdateContainer(
            builder =>
            {
                builder.RegisterModule(new ReflectionSurrogateModule());

                builder.RegisterModule(new AzureModule(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));

                //var store = new InMemoryDataStore();

                var store = new TableBotDataStore(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BotStorage"]);

                builder.Register(c => store)
                    .Keyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(AzureModule.Key_DataStore)
                    .AsSelf()
                    .SingleInstance();
            });
```

In my ICredentialProvider implementation (as outlined in the articles examples). If I store the customers connection string along side their App ID and Password, is it possible to pull that reference in the dependency injection above based on the customer/bot serialising the data store and then save/read that data to the customers Azure table storage?

Comment: `If I store the customers connection string along side their App ID and Password, is it possible to pull that reference in the dependency injection above based on the customer/bot serialising the data store and then save/read that data to the customers Azure table storage?` Can you clarify more about your requirement? do you want to store storage connection string(s) with Microsoft appId and password into a Dictionary, and access the storage connection string when you register TableBotDataStore?

Comment: @FeiHan Pretty much. They don't have to be stored all together, but I thought storing the azure connection string(s) alongside the app id was the most logical place for it. My thinking is that I can pull the connection string based on the Http context identity claim (similar to what is achieved with multiple authentication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a custom bot data store that implements `IBotDataStore<BotData>` and use that. I was able to get a simple one that created the same `TableBotDataStore` each time. Below is what I used and a break point in the constructor gets hit each time I send a message.

```
public class CustomBotStore : IBotDataStore<BotData>
{
    private IBotDataStore<BotData> _store;

    public CustomBotStore()
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BotState"].ConnectionString;

        _store = new TableBotDataStore(connString, "testbotdata"); // requires Microsoft.BotBuilder.Azure Nuget package 
    }

    public Task<bool> FlushAsync(IAddress key, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return _store.FlushAsync(key, cancellationToken);
    }

    public Task<BotData> LoadAsync(IAddress key, BotStoreType botStoreType, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return _store.LoadAsync(key, botStoreType, cancellationToken);
    }

    public Task SaveAsync(IAddress key, BotStoreType botStoreType, BotData data, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return _store.SaveAsync(key, botStoreType, data, cancellationToken);
    }
}


public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

        Conversation.UpdateContainer(
        builder =>
        {
            builder.RegisterModule(new AzureModule(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));

            builder.Register(c => new CustomBotStore())
                .Keyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(AzureModule.Key_DataStore)
                .AsSelf()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        });
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what the implications of having an instance per lifetime scope are because the sample uses a single instance. But you should be able to use this and then inspect the `HttpContext` in the constructor and use the correct connection string.

Comment: I ended up simplifying this further by calling a new TableBotDataStore in the autofac register lambda expression and using the GetAppIDFromClaims() extension method on the User claims Identity to pull a connection string out of a dictionary.

Comment: where did you add your autofac register lambda expression? Have you iterated all your tenants in the Application_Start() method to do that? how did you solve to manage many TableBotDataStore instances (one per tenant)?